# HTML Implementing MaxLength but ignoring decimals

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm implementing a text box in HTML with the MaxLength attribute. I want it to be 4 digits only but ignoring decimals. So a user should only be able to write a number from 0 to 9999. however, I want them to be able to add decimals like 9011.22. What would be the best way to go about implementing this? Will it need some kind of javascript?

here is my HTML tag:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
```

Comment: maxlength will count characters.  You could use a number input with max instead, which will actually check that the number is lower than the one you set us a maximum. Look for min and max here: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_form_attributes.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [number type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number), it will allow you to set a `min` and a `max`. You can then use the `step` attribute to control the number of decimals.

- You can add the `required` property to make this field required.
- You can use `this.checkValidity()` in the `onblur` event to validate before submitting.

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="lastname" value="Mouse" min="0" max="9999" step="0.01">
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: It says "step is not a valid attribute of element input"

Comment: did you change `type="text"` to `type="number"`?